# windows phone 8 - 50 alarm limitation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scheduled-tasks, alarm

I am developing an app in windows mobile phone v8. it requires to add 60 alarms(2 alarms per day) but there is limitation of 50 alarms described in [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202946%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
On button click i have to create all 60 alarms  on loop or i can add 10 alarms with possiblity to add 10 more when the last alarms starts or ends. I have searched but didnt find any solution. 
Is there any event when alarm dialog opens or alarms starts maybe i can check if the alarm is last then i can add 10 more alarms and removing or replacing previous alarms. any suggestions ?
here is my code

QList has the value taken from database

```
for (int i = 0; i < QList.Count; i++)
           {
               //double seconds = 60.0 * (double)i;
               string alarmName = "Sehar Alert " + i.ToString();
               Alarm alarm = new Alarm(alarmName);
               alarm.Content = "Its Sehar time in " + Cityname + " City. " + i.ToString();


               var reminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(alarmName);


               if (reminder != null)
               {
                   ScheduledActionService.Remove(alarmName);
               }
               string datetime = QList[i].date +" "+ QList[i].Sehar;
               DateTime sherTime = Convert.ToDateTime(datetime);
               if (sherTime > sherT)
               {

                   // DateTime seharTime = new DateTime(2014, 6, 10, 10, 12, 0);
                   alarm.BeginTime = sherTime;// DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds);
                   alarm.Sound = new Uri("Assets/Sounds/azan1.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
                   //  alarm.ExpirationTime = alarm.BeginTime.AddSeconds(10.0);

                   alarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;

                   ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
               }
               // Aftar time in Different City
               string IftarName = "Iftar Alert " + i.ToString();
               Alarm Ifatealarm = new Alarm(IftarName);
               Ifatealarm.Content = "Its Aftar time in " + Cityname + " City. " + i.ToString();


               var Iftarreminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(IftarName);


               if (Iftarreminder != null)
               {
                   ScheduledActionService.Remove(IftarName);
               }
               string Iftardatetime = QList[i].date + " " + QList[i].Iftar;
               DateTime IfTarTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Iftardatetime);
               if (IfTarTime > sherT)
               {


                   // DateTime seharTime = new DateTime(2014, 6, 10, 10, 12, 0);
                   Ifatealarm.BeginTime = sherTime;// DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds);
                   Ifatealarm.Sound = new Uri("Assets/Sounds/azan1.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
                   //  alarm.ExpirationTime = alarm.BeginTime.AddSeconds(10.0);

                   Ifatealarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;

                   ScheduledActionService.Add(Ifatealarm);
               }

           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `App.Xaml.cs`, you can subscribe to the `Obscured` and `Unobscured` events of your RootFrame.

```
 RootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(RootFrame_Obscured);
    RootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(RootFrame_Unobscured);
```

When the alarm pops up, `RootFrame_Unobscured` will be fired; after you dismiss it, `RootFrame_Obscured` will be fired.

Comment: iam kinda new to windows phone can you give more detail where to put rootframe.obscured + =..... code

Comment: go to Constructor for the Application object. that is public App() n code like below:public App()
        {            RootFrame.Obscured += RootFrame_Obscured;
RootFrame.Unobscured += RootFrame_Unobscured;
}

Comment: i have added this code but RootFrame_Unobscured breakpoint is  not fired

Comment: it should fire. look here for more reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206954(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I think it will fire only if the application is open.